# How to use createRef() instead of this.refs?

Tags: reactjs, dom, undefined, ref, refs

I work on a project which use *"react-notification-alert"* from creativetim. In their doc they show an [example](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/react-notification-alert) to use their alert. This works basicly with **this.ref** but I know that is depreciated, so I tried to replace it by using createRef() like below:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props);
    this.notifRef = React.createRef();

    myFunc(){
        this.notifRef.current.notify.notificationAlert(options);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <NotificationAlert ref={this.notifRef} />
        <button onClick={() => this.myFunc()}>Hey</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But problem is that the console show me

> Cannot read property 'notificationAlert' of undefined

I tried many solution, and saw a lot of answer on stack, but I have difficulties to understand how it could works.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between string constants and createRef is createRef stores data in `current` field, as string constant stores it in this.refs[stringConstant].

So your code could be:

```js
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      this.notifRef = React.createRef();
    }
    myFunc(){
        this.notifRef.current.notificationAlert(options);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <NotificationAlert ref={this.notifRef} />
        <button onClick={() => this.myFunc()}>Hey</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for your explaination Nikita. Now it works correctly ! I understand better now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
     super();
     this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind( this );
  }

  myFunc(){
     this.notifRef.current.notify.notificationAlert(options);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NotificationAlert ref={ e=> this.notifRef = e } />
        <button onClick={ this.myFunc }>Hey</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```